# Github Emoji tag to Emojies

Tags: javascript, regex, string, github, github-api

I've collected description of some github repos. Some of the have github emoji tags. I would like to convert them to emoji images.

I have the following,

```
var innerContent = "<li><span class='link'><a href='" + JSON.parse(response)[i].html_url + "' target='_blank'>" + JSON.parse(response)[i].name + "<span> - " + String(JSON.parse(response)[i].description).replace(/(:.+:)/g, 'Do Something here') + "</span>" + "<br/></a></span></li>"
```

How can I convert them images? I know that I can get their images from Github API. But I am not able to remove `:` from the description.

Comment: Can you give some sample data?

Comment: Check out this library: https://github.com/iamcal/emoji-data
Has been super useful for me :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many emojify libraries on GitHub, which converts emoji tag to emoji character. Like this the official GitHub one https://github.com/github/gemoji and this one https://github.com/mrowa44/emojify.

You need to find one suiting your case.

Technically, regex can do this, but it will be a huge regex to cover all the emojis.